# How should someone react to this version of Zone of Truth?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, house-rules

Well, I guess the Actual question would be "How the save?" but that's terrible grammar.

In my group, we have a house-rule that makes the use of Zone of Truth a bit more... useful, for lack of a better word.

The rule is as follows: *Successfully making the save against Zone of Truth does not allow the person who made the save to ignore the effects; it only makes them aware of the effect, thus allowing them to refuse to answer or to phrase their sentences less directly to avoid deliberate false-hoods while still not speaking clearly. If the save is failed, then the person finds her/himself unable to prevent her/himself from speaking anything but the most direct truth possible.*

My question is: **For people that fail the save, what is a good way to depict them not realizing they're being forced to speak the truth?** It would be obvious, of course, but the main issue is the first few sentences, when they've yet to become aware of it. Does anyone else use a similar rule, or have any experience with a similar situation?

Comment: Just to point out that there's still a good use for the standard Zone of Truth -- if someone claims to be telling the truth, you can ask them to voluntarily fail the save.